# TypeError: update_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, dash

Недавно стала изучать dash app. и столкнулась с ошибкой:

```
Callback error updating body_div.children
Traceback: TypeError: update_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Мой код:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
table = dash_table.DataTable(
    columns=[
        {"name": col, "id": col, "selectable": True} for col in df.columns
    ],
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    id='datatable-interact')
app.layout = html.Div([

    html.Div([
        html.Button('Update data', id='update-button', n_clicks=0,
                    style=btn_style),
        # dcc.Interval(id='refresh-interval', interval=5000, n_intervals=0),
        dcc.Download(id="download"),
        html.Br(),
    ], style=div_style,
    ),
    html.Br(),
     html.Div([html.Div([table],  
                           id='body_div', ),
                  dcc.Loading(
                      id="loading_item",
                      type="default",
                      # type="circle",
                      parent_style=loading_style
                  ),
                  ],
                 style=div_style),
    ])
])

@callback(
    [Output('body_div', 'children'),
     Output('loading_item', 'parent_style'),
    ],
    Input('update-button', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True, )
def update_data(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    updated_df = df.copy()
    return updated_df.to_dict('records')
```

Что я делаю не так. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: `loading_item` откуда взялся? В вашем макете вижу только `loading`. `update_data(n_clicks)` можно очень грязно поправить на `update_data(*args)`, но похорошему на дебажить и смотреть что там вам прилетает , по части невоспроизводимого кода сложно что-то утверждать.

Comment: loading_item это тоже самое, что и loading, неправильно переписала. но проблема не в этом